# VM's unable to communicate via hostname

Tags: linux, troubleshooting

This is very strange behavior of `SSH`, when trying to connect the machine with the hostname it gets refused or hanged. but when connecting with the IP it works fine. unable to ping the host `object2`. These are all VM's.

```
[root@centseven ]# ssh -vvv object2.com
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to object2.com [10.0.0.51] port 22.
```

entry of `/etc/hosts` file on the `centserver`

```
[root@centseven ~]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

10.0.0.31       compute1.com compute1
10.0.0.41       block1.com block1
10.0.0.51       object2.com object2
```

Other host are working fine and are able to ping.

```
[root@centseven ~]# ip r
default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3  proto static  metric 100
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15  metric 100
192.168.56.0/24 dev enp0s8  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.56.11  metric 100


[root@object2 ~]# ip r
default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3
10.0.0.0/24 dev enp0s8  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.52
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s3  scope link  metric 1002
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s8  scope link  metric 1003

[root@compute1 ~]# ip r
default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3  proto static  metric 100
10.0.0.0/24 dev enp0s8  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.31  metric 100
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15  metric 100
```

Comment: The question sounded like you would show us what worked and what didn't but instead you show IP addresses tables of different hosts.  What happens differently when you use the IP versus the name?

Comment: Do I read you right when I understand that `ping object2` fails but `ping 10.0.0.51` works?  If that is the case, what error do you get?

Comment: Newly installed vm done no changes so for & there is no error for `ping object2` it just hangs.

Comment: But pinging the IP gets replies?

Comment: Yes, ip ping gives reply.

Comment: Does it show the same IP when pinging the host name, or does it perhaps freeze before resolving it?

Comment: It gets freeze. nothing is shown below the `ping ip` command .

Comment: I'll assume you mean `ping object2` freezes.  This is strange!  Does `dig any object2` return anything or freeze too?

Comment: Its getting freeze too.

Comment: That obviously indicates a DNS issue.  Did you create a DNS zone for it?  If so, try restarting the DNS server.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the first sentence completely: You mean SSH works with the IP address (but not the hostname), and ping doesn't work at all? (should it be allowed?) Your `hosts` shows `object2` as `10.0.0.51`, but on the `ip route` there's `src 10.0.0.52`, does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: @ilkkachu:  I asked OP to try `dig` to see if it was relevant to the `ping` freezing and it apparently is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add record for object2.com to /etc/hosts file if you're not using DNS. If you are using DNS, make sure it's aware of object2.com host.